Upgrade Jammy to Noble brokes up LXC container

If I'll install Ubuntu Jammy (host running on Jammy too) in LXC container, and try to upgrade to Noble like this:
do-release-upgrade -d
While apt upgrading system, container will be simply stopped, and can't be started/accessed anymore:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Why is the image not showing?
If create container with Noble release (lxc-create -t ubuntu -n test2 -- --release noble), then container won't start too.

Is that a bug, or I doing something wrong?

Confusing question. Did you try the upgrade and it failed or have you not tried yet. The question seems to say both.

Yes, of course I tried the upgrade and it failed, container simlpy "stopped". You can test by yourself on virtual machine with Ubuntu 22.04.

lxc-attach test2 does not seem to be a valid command, according to man lxd-attach

Also classic mis-use of -d in a release-upgrade. It won't do what you expect.

lxd-attach is for LXD, my case is LXC.

The use case (LXC vs LXD) does not seem relevant. Using an invalid command SHOULD result in an error...and your output shows that using an invalid command DID result in an error. If you believe LXC vd LXD to be relevant, please edit your question to clearly explain. Avoid commenting on your own question.

Command is completely correct, the problem there that's container simply not starting with Ubuntu Noble, so it cannot attach. Container won't run, get it?
